# "Retrieving the COM class factory for component..." error while synchronizing using SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am testing a sample code for SQL Server CE Sync:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(ClientConnectionString);

            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(ServerConnectionString);

            // create the sync orhcestrator
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
            // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);

            // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
            // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);

            // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

            // execute the synchronization process
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            // print statistics
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
}
```

At line

```
SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

I am getting this exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I tried changing the target platform to x64, but no success. I searched SO and other web sites but didn't get any prefect answer. Please tell me how to get rid of this exception? And what it actually means?

**UPDATE**
I changed the platform to x86 and now its not giving that exception but its showing following exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I checked the server in SQL Server Configuration Manager and its running fine and accessible from Management Studio.

Comment: Try changing the Target 'platform' ?

Comment: @AccessDenied yes both 'target platform' n 'platform' are set to x64

Comment: Earlier issue is resolved, Now you have a different issue, it looks like the SQL server is not accessible.